# Can any one explain me this question Consider the searching problem

Tags: python, list, algorithm, linear-search

**Can any one explain me this Question?**
I am not understanding what it is asking me to do!

> Question:
> Consider the searching problem.
> Input: a sequence of n numbers A = [A1,A2,...An] and a value v.
> Output: an index i such that v = A[i] or the special value NIL if v does not appear in A.
> Write pseudo-code for linear search, which scans the sequence, looking for v. Using a loop invariant fulfilling the three necessary properties.

My Answer:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

n = int(input("Enter a number :"))

if n in a:
    print(f"{n} is in the sequence")
else:
    print("NIL")
```

**Is this answer correct?**

Comment: You need to give the index of the value.

Comment: @Guy  Do you mean like if n = 11 i should display the position of the n value in that list, like it will be a[11]?

Comment: If `a = [3, 6, 4]`  and `n = 3` you need print 0.

Answer (score 0):

You must work with the indexes of the list so the answer might be a code like:

```
A = [11,10,0,13,6,25,9,17,2,19]

v = 6

for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] == v:
        print(i)
        break
else:
    print("NIL")
```

For this example the answer will be 4 because the number that is given from the input is 6 and we can find that number ( v ) at the 4th index of our list ( A ).
Hope that was helpful.